# Is that adv. + noun. right in grammar?

Tags: grammar

For example,

> Such a procedure, however, must make use of the **specifically** human capacity for self-detachment inherent in a sense
> of humor.

Which is an excerpt of [Viktor Frankl’s 1947 book, *Man's Search for Meaning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27s_Search_for_Meaning)

Would *specifical* or *specific* be better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term "specifically human" uses "human" to be an adjective, with "specifically" being an adverb modifier to the adjective following it. In the provided sentence, the noun is not "human", but "capacity".

"The capacity [for self-detachment] *(n.)* is specifically *(adv.)* human *(adj.)*."